# SAS Obtaining Words before a Keyword

Tags: sas

I am currrently using 9.4 SAS. I have the following sentence in a column:

"BELINDA S LEE IS A PARTNER IN THE SAN FRANCISCO OFFICE OF LATHAM & WATKINS. SHE IS A MEMBER OF THE FIRM'S LITIGATION & TRIAL DEPARTMENT. HER PRACTICE FOCUSES ON ANTITRUST AND COMPLEX LITIGATION."

I am wanting to scan the text for the WORD "DEPARTMENT" keyword and when it comes across it take the whole of the sentence before that keyword and then stop when it comes to a space or full stop. From this I will create a new column with the following information "SHE IS A MEMBER OF THE FIRM'S LITIGATION & TRIAL DEPARTMENT".

Is it possible to scan a text column with a keyword like this to obtain the rest of the sentence before the keyword?

Thanks

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to break the string into sentences first.  Then test each sentence to see if it contains the word you are looking for.  If it does, output that record.

```
data have;
input = "BELINDA S LEE IS A PARTNER IN THE SAN FRANCISCO OFFICE OF LATHAM & WATKINS. SHE IS A MEMBER OF THE FIRM'S LITIGATION & TRIAL DEPARTMENT. HER PRACTICE FOCUSES ON ANTITRUST AND COMPLEX LITIGATION.";
run;

data want;
set have;
format out $2000.;

n = countw(input,".");
do i=1 to n;
    out = scan(input,i,".");
    if index(out,"DEPARTMENT") then 
        output;
end;
drop i n;
run;
```

So here I use the `COUNTw()` function to count the number of sentences delimited by a '.'. Then I loop over those, getting each with the `SCAN()` function. I test to see if "DEPARTMENT" is in that sentence and if so, output.